# Stream closed error when getting charset

Tags: java, character-encoding, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm having issues with the following code:

```
try (
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(is,
                     Charset.forName(SidFileUtils.charsetDetection(is))
                   )
                 );
    ) {

        br.readLine();
        br.readLine();

        for (String line = br.readLine() ; line != null ; line = br.readLine()) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    } catch (ExceptionTechnique | IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier " + file.getName(), e);
    }
```

This part of the code: `Chasrset.forName(...)` is giving me a `Stream Closed error`. I think it's because I'm using the `InputStream` item twice and it has already been consumed but I'm not sure.

Can you help me understand what is wrong with this code please ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: The `charsetDetection` method probably reads the stream then closes it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the charsetDetection has no other option to read the stream further. Some streams can mark and reset the read position *when* the specific InputStream supports it.

```
if (in.markSupported()) {
    final int maxBytesNeededForDetection = 8192;
    in.mark(maxBytesNeededForDetection);
    ... do the detection
    in.reset();
} else {
    throw IllegalState();
}
```

`BufferedInputStream` indeed supports it, but only upto the buffer size; otherwise an `IOException("Resetting to invalid mark");` is raised.

One then should specify the buffer size in the constructor.

**In this case** it seems no `mark/reset` is used by the detection. Quite logical because of the partial coverage of such a technique.

```
Charset charset = null;
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    Charset charset = Charset.forName(SidFileUtils.charsetDetection(is));
}
if (charset != null) {
    ...
}
```